# MP3 Program for bedtime mp3 player reading?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, mp3-player

Is there any mp3 player which can be set to play a certain playlist of mp3s, and when the playlist ends, it turns the computer off?

That way it could be used to play something while I sleep, and I don't have to worry about the computer staying on throughout the night.

An alternative would be, if there is no computer input for 1 hour, it then turns the computer off.

Any suggestions?

I'm on Windows xp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [whole bunch of auto-shutdown plugins for Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/plugins/search/shutdown).

Most popular one is called [shutdown](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/shutdown/171292):

[image: Shutdown plugin, image #1]

[image: Shutdown plugin, image #2]

Comment: I've installed this, but have no idea how to find it or use it

Comment: As shown on the first screenshot, after installing one additional menu entry will appear in the context menu when you right-click on the tray icon. Just check it, and PC will auto-shutdown after playlist will stop. Please take in mind that this may not happen if you have repeating playlist.

Comment: Thanks, that way of getting the menu is verry unintuitive

Answer (score 2):

The application linked below will shutdown your computer in a user-specified number of minutes, regardless of which mp3 player you are using.

http://www.winamp.com/plugin/winamp-sleeper-application/138943

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at power options in the control panel. You can set what happens when the computer is idle for a specified time.

[image]

[This page](http://www.lancelhoff.com/adjust-windows-xp-power-options/) has more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the computer to hibernate if it's idle. I can't remember where the options are exactly in XP, but in 7 they're in **Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options**

There should be a option to put the computer to sleep after a certain amount of time.

As long as your mp3 player leaves your machine completely idle this will kick in and shut the machine down 30 minutes (say) after your playlist ends.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this batch file, which you could save to your desktop, and drag an `.mp3` file onto it to start it.

```
@echo off
mplayer2.exe /play /close %1
shutdown /s /t 0
:EOF
```

You could change the program and arguments to fit any media player which has the ability to play a file and then exit.  I could not find any for WMP12, which I have on Windows 7, but I think this should work for WMP in XP.

---

***update:*** I just re-read your question and realised you wanted to play a playlist.  I think Winamp is your best option then.  There are ways to get `WMP` to play using `.pls` playlist files (which would make this solution viable with WMP), but that is a another question.  It would still work with other media players which play playlist files and have command line arguments for playing an exiting though, so I won't delete the answer.